# How would harpies get supplies up and down their mountain homes?

Tags: technology, fantasy-races, mythical-creatures, mountains, logistics

Clearly, harpies can fly up and down between their mountain homes and the ground. They may be able to do this while carrying a considerable weight. But that's still the hardest, most manual way of hauling goods for them, and it will be tiring.

So, I'm asking about alternate solutions they might have, for moving goods up or down the mountain, for harpies with a society more developed than doing everything by hand.

Speaking of which, we'll assume they have hands, for simplicity (so we don't need to worry about what you can make without them). As for technology, I'd focus on pre-modern (so before the 17th century), but I think we'd all be interested to hear modern interpretations if anyone would like to share them.

As for an example of what they might do.... Ski-lifts? Parachutes? Gliders? It also depends on how fragile the cargo is, of course. I guess food would be most common, but more delicate items like pottery could be involved.

Oh, and zip-lines. I was curious if you could do anything with a zip-line, would be nice if you could zip small cargo over crevices and possibly between two peaks, gradually going down the mountain. Not sure how much of a zip-line you could even make, prior to modern materials, though.

## Details

### Distance

This varies a lot. For most cases, the harpies are trying to take stuff from the base of the mountain to 4~12K feet in altitude. So figure a thousand feet or more above ground level, so about a thousand feet of altitude.

Not sure what else was implied when, I said they lived up in mountains.

Of course, some of the transport, if it's gliders or the like, it would have the option of sending good a pretty considerable distance, for purposes of trade. So again, I'm being asked for information that precludes the transport options....

### Cargo

This really depends on capacity of the transport system... if the elevator can only take 50kg, you're not going to put anything over 50kg on it, are you? I already stated food is the main commodity, and crafts such as pottery are a possible trade item.

### Material

I already said pre-modern technology, so anything before the 1600s is game. And material depends on the transport system... so I don't know why JBH is insisting I answer my own question under threat of closure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118061/discussion-on-question-by-johnny-how-would-harpies-get-supplies-up-and-down-thei).

Comment: It's unclear what harpies have to do with this question if you're giving them hands. They'd use stairs and ramps, just like we did at that stage of development. This is less worldbuilding than a straight history question.

Answer (score 3):

one technology i can think off that can be done before premodern times is elevator, it exist even during greek era.

for example like this

from:https://landmarkelevator.com/history-of-elevator-technology/

[image]

[image]

probably require multiple elevator checkpoint to lift them up to the top.

> As early as 236 BC, the ancient Greek mathematician, Archimedes built
> the first known elevator. The achievement is recorded in the works of
> Vitruvius, a Roman author and architect who lived more than 150 years
> later. Ancient elevators such as Archimedes’ typically consisted of a
> wooden platform or box drawn by hemp ropes through a vertical open
> shaft and powered by men or animals operating a capstan. These devices
> were used primarily to lift heavy loads such as water or building
> materials. While the talented Archimedes is generally credited with
> inventing the elevator, his device and others like it were only the
> earliest forerunners of modern passenger elevators.

> Vertical transportation technology remained much the same in subsequent
> centuries until Louis XV of France commissioned a device know as “the
> flying chair” to be installed in the Palace at Versailles.
> Blaise-Henri Arnoult adapted and built a design originally developed
> by Count de Villayer. The chair connected the apartments of the king
> to those of his mistress on the upper level of the palace, and was
> operated by pulling a cord which was connected to counterweights by
> way of a pulley system. Consequently, the flying chair represents the
> first known use of an elevator specifically for passengers.

regarding handling fragile cargo, put cushion in it, as OP also mention from straw, to feather (which i assume the harpies wont lack off), cloth, and such, and put some harpies to protect or guard the fragile cargo.

i dont know the mechanism of ski-lift, but judging from the elevator mechanism maybe it possible to do.

Comment: I like the pictures! Elevators would definitely be part of the logistics network. They would even get horsepowered ones, with an affluent harpy civilization. Elevators are a simple way to move freight up the mountains, or down the mountains if it has to be moved carefully.

Comment: That was where I was going. Even a simple rope and pulley with a rock on one end and a basket on the other, dragging a load along the side of a mountain.